# how to open close navigation drawer click on image view.i am not using action bar ?.

Tags: android

[I am using linear layout in drawer layout.in linear layout has one image view i want to click the image view then open the navigation drawer but it is not done so i am posting one image so please give me suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSqrr.png)

Answer (score 1):

To open the NavigationDrawer use this :-

`mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`

To close the NavigationDrawer use this :-

`mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`

Answer (score 0):

there is one solution you can set the image as action bar app icon and you can open drawer on click of that image-

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

this line of code  will Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

Do this in onClick of imageView:

```
if(drawer.isOpened()){ drawer.closeDrawer(your_drawer_view);}
else drawer.openDrawer(your_drawer_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `((YourActivityWithDrawer)getActivity()).drawerLayout.openDrawer(your_drawer);`

where:

- `YourActivityWithDrawer` is your Activity containing drawer,
- `drawerLayout` is your DrawerLayout object
- `your_drawer` is the actual drawer object.